# Autolayout - arrange elements vertically with space in between programatically?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uilabel, frame, autolayout

I'm currently manually positioning my UI elements, which gets annoying if I update the text or add elements as I have to recalculate all the positions each time.

Is there a way using autolayout to size and positions the elements, for example as follows, no matter how much text the labels contain?

```
UILabel (multiline, variable height)
[20px gap]
UILabel (multiline, variable height)
[20px gap]
UIButton
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will look something like this

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSDictionary *_viewsDictionary;
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // First create your controls - you can just use CGRectZero
        _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label1 setText:@"Some text";

        _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label2 setText:@"Some text 2";

        _button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        // Then just add them to your as a sub view
        [self addSubview:self.currentBalanceLabel];
        [self addSubview:_nameLabel];
        [self addSubview:_button];

        // Put them in an NSDictionary - this is a macro and will be used when setting up the contraints below
        _viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_nameLabel, _currentBalanceLabel,_button);

        // This tells the view to run update contraints
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    }
}


- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    // Using the _viewsDictionary, we must tell always tell how all the controls will be setup both 
    // horizontally and vertically.  In this case wear are going to tell the label to take the entire width
    // The rest of the vies will be aligned on the left below
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_label1]-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];

    //Add the contraints
    [self addConstraints:constraints];

    // Next setup the vertical contraints.  This is what you asked about spefically, label - 20 - label - 20 - button
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_labelq]-20-[_label2]-20-[_button]"
                                                          options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:_viewsDictionary];


    [self addConstraints:constraints];


}

@end
```

Comment: To expand a bit on this: conceptually what's happening is that Yes, you can set it up. To do that, you need to manually update the constraints on the items as your program is running (vs using just the constraints added in Interface Builder). The above code does that, taken from an app that's working in a TableView. For your purposes, the important stuff is the constraint creation in the updateConstraints method.